# Time function with smallest possible granularity?

Tags: python, time

```
x = time.time_ns()
y = time.time_ns()
print(x == y)
```

Ideally, I'd like the above function to print `False` without sticking a bunch of (unnecessary code) in between- is there a good way to do this in Python? Or do the limits of granularity for Python variables make this impossible?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: The reason I ask this is because I'm trying to implement an LRU replacement policy for a cache model I'm building- but this is more of a general question than anything.

Comment: But `time.time_ns()` won't cost too much time(less than "ns").To get the wasted time of `time.time_ns()`,maybe you could consider using `timeit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee the system actually has a sufficiently granular clock, but [`time.perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) will give you the highest granularity available. The Python documentation claims it uses a clock with the "highest available resolution to measure a short duration".

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a performance counter, i.e. a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short duration. It does include time elapsed during sleep and is system-wide. The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid.

There is also `time.perf_counter_ns`, which is similar to the above but returns the time as an integer number of nanoseconds, avoiding floating-point precision limitations (though the value is not guaranteed to actually have nanosecond accuracy).

`time.perf_counter` is the default timer for the `timeit` module ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/afff51fc09993dff1693aacb440221314b163409/Lib/timeit.py#L62)).